# How do I create email variable outside of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

this returns error "SignIn:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

```
<script>
    var email = document.getElementById("email")
    function validate() {
        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.value)) {
            location = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/SendMail";
            return (true)
        }
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
        return (false)
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: By the way the reason I am not defining it in the function is because I want to eventually store the variable in "localStorage" so I can use the information stored in the text box on another page. Please ask questions if this does not make sense

Comment: Something is wrong with the email object.

Comment: Is there an HTML element with the id "email" when this code is run? Hint: if this `<script>` tag is in the header or in the body above the element's tag, then it doesn't exist yet when the code is run.

Comment: yes there is. So your saying I have to declare the <script></script> tags after I declare <input type="input" id = "email" class="input-bar">

Comment: Yes @Caleb that's right

Comment: Thank you so much. The more I think about it the more stupid I feel. I mean obviously it has to be declared after <input> because its outside of a function. Thank you I wish you well

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to create

```
<input type="text" id="email">
```

Than run this script in the bottom of input means at the footer it will work.
And make sure you run that function.

```
validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try having an outer function, in IIFE pattern.

```js
<script>
   (function(){
   var email = document.getElementById("email")
    function validate() {
        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.value)) {
            location = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/SendMail";
            return (true)
        }
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
        return (false)
    }})();   
</script>
```